# Series RLC circuit problem

Tags: current, circuit-analysis, passive-networks

[image]

[image]

I have attached my attempt and the solution provided by my instructor. I am confused on 2 things

1. what it means by "the circuit is in quiescent state" ?
2. why is he getting sqrt(8) in the current equation ?

Edit1: I have also attempted the same problem using Laplace

[image]

Comment: R u sure given ans is right? Yours seems to be perfectly fine

Comment: Yes, it was asked in ESE 2018 held on 7th jan 2018.

Comment: @Deep https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/349472/ordinary-differential-relay-problem?noredirect=1#comment832588_349472 please take a look

Comment: I'm not eligible enough yet to ans that question, thanks for A2A though. (It seems Andy Aka commented that given ans is wrong (in link of question you pointed me to) , I've already found enough mistakes in Gateforum's material (though I've ready only one book yet) to tell that it's not at all trustworthy source).

Comment: Thanks @Deep, btw it is a previously asked problem in gate EE.

Comment: you can check official answer key then to see if Gateforum printed the right answer, sometimes GATE gives Marks to All if there were not enough data given... btw, best of luck if you're opting for gate 18, I'll be there in 19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem happened when you differentiated the both sides of the equation. 100 Volts, which is a constant, became 0 in the left hand side of equation after differentiation. Don't you think there is a problem in it ? Cz even if it was any other number there, it would go zero and you will still end up in the same solution. Say, 25 Volts. You will get the same solution. But in the circuit , current has indeed changed. In fact you can never always differentiate both sides of some f(i) = g(i) equation and say the relation will still hold. Because you can differentiate the both sides ONLY if the equality f(i) = g(i) holds true for all real values of i. This is a heterogenous integro-differential equation. In this case the complete solution = CF + PI, mathematically. Both CF and PI have to be calculated. You have calculated only CF by neglecting LHS constant, and hence it is only partial solution. Maybe math stack exchange can provide more insight into this on how to solve this. Otherwise it's better to solve the equation in Laplace domain rather than in time domain. It is straight forward and easy to solve.

**EDIT:**

Your laplace solution is correct. So I think the book is wrong. If you take inverse transform of their solution, you will end up in a wrong RLC equation for that circuit. The correct series RLC ckt equations' deno should look like : $$s^2 + 2s(R/2L)+ (1/LC) = s^2 + 4s + 8 $$

While in their solution, it will evaluate to a wrong one:
$$ s^2 + 4s + 12 $$

Comment: Please check my attempt using laplace

Comment: Yes, I differentiated and lost 100 but that information is there in form of variable c2. I don't think there is anything wrong by differentiating the equation.

Comment: Suppose x^2 = 100. If you try to differentiate both sides and say that solution is x = 0. That is wrong. So differentiating both sides of an equation never gives solution always. Here c2's value cant be determined cz that information is lost by differentiating both sides. There are two parts of solution to a differential equation -> PI and CF. What you found by differentiating both sides and neglecting the RHS constant is called CF or complimentary function.

Comment: It is not complete solution. PI has to be found incorporating the constant and added with CF to get the complete solution. Or else Boundary conditions have to be analysed.

Comment: But your laplace solution is correct. So I think the book is wrong. If you take inverse transform of their solution, you will end up in an invalid RLC equation. Series RLC ckt equations' deno should look like : s^2 + 2s(R/2L)+ 1/LC. Which is not in their solution.

Comment: Actually RHS will be always 100 for all values of i - says KVL.

Comment: Yeah, it seems whatever question source he is referring to is wrong.

Comment: good catch bro... But still that gives partial solution only. For complete solution, PI has to be calculated too.

Comment: Oh yes, PI has to be added into CF that's for sure. That's why I love Laplace 

Comment: lol yah....it's better for us, the electrical and electronics people.

Answer (score 2):

> what it means by "the ckt is in quiescent state" ?

It means that there was no energy in either the inductor or capacitor prior to the voltage being applied.

> why is he getting sqrt(8) in the current equation ?

With an inductor of 0.5 henries and a capacitor of 0.25 farads, the natural resonant frequency is \$\sqrt8\$ radians per second.

This is from the equation \$\omega_n = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{LC}} \$

In other words there will be a damped oscillation in the current starting at a peak and decaying with a natural frequency of \$\sqrt8\$ radians per second.

Comment: where I did mistake in my calculation ?

Comment: @NikhilKashyap look at example 1 on this page: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/ComplexRoots.aspx and see if it clears things up. I think the problem is how you translated a 2nd order diff equation with complex roots to sin and cosine terms.

Comment: No, He did the same thing as me in example 1. Please check once more.

Comment: I think it will be wd rather than wn & wd=wn*sqrt(1-zeta^2)=2. So, it should be 2 not sqrt(8).

Comment: Maybe try asking on maths stack exchange if all the doubts are about the math. As far as I'm concerned in analysing the frequency domain, the natural frequency is \$\sqrt8\$ rads per second and that will be the decaying waveform in the transient response. Maybe use LTSpice to simulate it?